# garbage screen on ubuntu Studio 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, screen, ubuntu-studio

I just upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04 on an HP Pavilion but get a garbage screen after logging on.  The top row is ok so I can see what programs  are running but the rest of the screen is garage. It seems that each row is offset a bit more each row.
Up to the login the screen is fine.  But then becomes unusable.

Comment: The only way this will work is in recovery mode

Comment: I went back to 18.04